# iPod Touch (OS 3.0) bluetooth connection to non apple device

Tags: ipod-touch

I need to know if I can programmatically connect my iPod Touch (OS 3.0) to a non apple blue tooth device, Using the Apple iPhone SDK.
I know that I can connect to other iPhone using GameKit API, But can I connect to other non apple Bluetooth devices for example an measuring device that send out real time data over blue tooth?

Answer (score 1):

To send or receive data either by wire or over Bluetooth any device must authorize itself with the iPhone with a dedicated authorization co-processor.  The chip costs < US$1 but the license fee you must pay to apple costs $4 per device

Comment: The $4 figure is not accurate. It really depends on volume. You must be part of Apple's MFi program to acquire the MFi license and buy this co-processor. Once you have the license, Apple has quarterly reporting requirements.